# How to adjust label=for in html+css

Tags: html, css

In the wep app I am developping I have the following situation:

[image]

so as you can see I must adjust the position of the label showing the red error messages. Inspecting the elements in the source code I have seen that I have to adjust:

```
<label for="oggetto" generated="true" class="error" style="display: block;">Seleziona almeno un oggetto</label>

<label for="allegato_contratto" generated="true" class="error">Allega il file del contratto col cliente</label>

<label for="allegato_preventivo" generated="true" class="error">Allega il file del preventivo</label>

<label for="modalita_pagamento" generated="true" class="error">Seleziona una modalità di pagamento</label>
```

Thus I have written this CSS sheet following a topic found here in StackOverflow:

```
label[for=oggetto] {
  padding: 76px 0px 0px 60px;
} 

label[for=modalita_pagamento] { 
  padding: 13px 0px 0px 60px;
}
```

This style sheet is correctly loaded in the html source but it does not work...do you know why?

Comment: Try posting a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for certain without seeing your relevant HTML and CSS, but most likely your CSS `label {}` code isn't specific enough. Try adding the `div` that contains the `label` elements to your CSS, like this:

```
.container-div label[for="oggetto"] {
  padding: 76px 0 0 60px;
}
```

Comment: Next time, please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with only the relevant HTML, and CSS. There's no CSS in this pastebin, so I can't check.

Comment: I don't know how to use JSFiddle and I would not know what code is useful and what is not

Comment: @Mave Next time, don't answer unless you have enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LoryLory StackOverflow is not a debugging service. If you don't know what code is useful and what not, figure it out by adding/removing code until you can reproduce the problem. We're willing to help you but you have to put in some effort.